# Page level skip/read in apache parquet

Tags: parquet

Question: Does Parquet have the ability to skip/read certain pages in a column chunk based on the query we run?

Can page header metadata help here?

http://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/

Under File Format, I read this statement and it seemed doubtful

*Readers are expected to first read the file metadata to find all the column chunks they are interested in. The columns chunks should then be read sequentially.*

Comment: You have to put your questions properly. Have to give details like what you have tried and where you are stuck. This kind questions might attract down votes.